# Candle Stick MP Chart android is not setting the candle stick size

Tags: android, graph, android-graphview

I am creating a CandleStick chart

> from API: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=10
>   Using Library: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

When I creating the chart with the count of values as X-axis, There is no problem (`ploat_point.add(new CandleEntry(i,high,low,open,close);` in for loop ).

But when I use `ploat_point.add(new CandleEntry(time,high,low,open,close);` in for loop, And parse X-axis values using my custom function.
i.e :

```
xAxis = candle_chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
                    @Override
                    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "getFormattedValue: " + (int) value);
                        return Utilities.timeStampToMonth((int) value + "");
                    }
                });
```

This time it is showing the graph only when the paint style is set to `Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE`, But It does not increasing the bar size with `candleDataSet.setBarSize()` . It depending only the `candleDataSet.setShadowWidth()`.

my code :

```
private void drawCandleStickChart(JSONArray dataArr) throws JSONException {

    mChart.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    ArrayList<CandleEntry> plot_point = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataArr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject point = dataArr.getJSONObject(i);
        int time = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(point.getString("time")));
        float open = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(point.getString("open")));
        float close = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(point.getString("close")));
        float high = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(point.getString("high")));
        float low = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(point.getString("low")));
        plot_point.add(new CandleEntry(time, high, low, open, close));
    }

    CandleDataSet cds = new CandleDataSet(plot_point, "Entries");
    cds.setShadowColor(Color.WHITE);


    cds.setDecreasingColor(Color.RED);
    cds.setDecreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    cds.setIncreasingColor(Color.GREEN);
    cds.setIncreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    cds.setNeutralColor(Color.BLUE);
    cds.setShowCandleBar(true);
    cds.setBarSpace(0.5f);
    cds.setShadowWidth(0.1f);

    cds.setHighlightEnabled(false);
    cds.setDrawValues(false);
    candle_chart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(20);

    CandleData cd = new CandleData(cds);

    candle_chart.setData(cd);
    candle_chart.invalidate();

    candle_chart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

I need X-axis as time and bar size is more than shadow please help me.

Comment: can you send code?

Comment: how do you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I acheived it by the changing constant value in library class 'CandleStickChartRenderer'. This has a method 'drawDataSet' with the code block

```
mBodyBuffers[0] = xPos - 0.5f + barSpace;
mBodyBuffers[1] = close * phaseY;
mBodyBuffers[2] = (xPos + 0.5f - barSpace);
mBodyBuffers[3] = open * phaseY;
```

This 0.5 constant you have to change to the some bigger value like 1000, As candle stick library has some issue with bigger x value.